# MYSQL : SELECT * FROM customer_table hide customer_password?

Tags: mysql

is there anyway to do a mysql select * and tell the query to - a field you don't want, or do you have to manually type them all out except for the one you don't want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely, no.

But here's a workaround. Create a `VIEW` of the table, eg

```
CREATE VIEW ViewName
AS
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, .... -- hide password here
    FROM tableName;
```

once the `VIEW` was created, you can now call it,

```
SELECT * FROM ViewName
```